# SQL Server 2008, Allocated stock to qty of sale order based on order type and order datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have FIFO allocated stock to sale order based on order type below:

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType )
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent'),
('D2','B',10,'Normal'),
('D3','C',11,'HotLine'),
('D1','D',20,'Normal'),
('D2','E',12,'Normal'),
('D2','D',40,'Normal');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',20),
('B',15),
('C',9),
('D',30),
('E',0)

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )

SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

the result:

```
dealercode  partcode    Stock   orderqty    Allocated   ordertype
D3  C   9   11  9   HotLine
D1  A   20  19  19  Urgent
D2  B   15  10  10  Normal
D1  D   30  20  20  Normal
D2  D   10  40  10  Normal
D2  E   0   12  0   Normal
```

I would prefer to allocated equally. ex. partcode D (Stock=30, orderqty 20 & 40 => Allocated (15,15). pls. kindly help me out.

**UPDATE:**
updated logic is allocated one time by qty=1 to each part and loop all parts till stock=0

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType )
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent'),
('D2','A',10,'Normal'),
('D3','A',11,'HotLine'),
('D1','A',20,'Normal'),
('D2','A',12,'Normal'),
('D1','A',40,'Normal');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',100);

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )

SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

result of FIFO allocated by orderqty a time:

```
dealercode  partcode    Stock   orderqty    Allocated   ordertype
D3  A   100 11  11  HotLine
D1  A   89  19  19  Urgent
D1  A   70  20  20  Normal
D1  A   50  40  40  Normal
D2  A   10  12  10  Normal
D2  A   0   10  0   Normal
```

I prefer to FIFO allocated by orderty=1 a time, so the result is more accurate:

```
dealercode  partcode    Stock   orderqty    Allocated   ordertype
D3  A   100 11  11  HotLine
D1  A   89  19  19  Urgent
D1  A   70  20  20  Normal
D1  A   50  40  28  Normal
D2  A   22  12  12  Normal
D2  A   10  10  10  Normal
```

in Excel allocated by qty=1 to all order:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first get count of total orders and total order qty for a part for a priority. based on this you can calculate if remaining stock from backorders is sufficient for total order of this priority or if it needs to be spread equally. 
Something like this.

**Data**

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType )
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent'),
('D2','B',10,'Normal'),
('D3','C',11,'HotLine'),
('D1','D',20,'Normal'),
('D2','E',12,'Normal'),
('D2','D',40,'Normal');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',20),
('B',15),
('C',9),
('D',30),
('E',0)
```

**Query**

```
;WITH ordertemp AS 
(
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode) 'StockPriority',
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode ORDER BY dealercode) rownum,
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode 
), ordercounttemp AS
(
    SELECT StockPriority,partcode,COUNT(*) totalorders, SUM(orderqty) totalorderqty 
    FROM ordertemp
    GROUP BY StockPriority,partcode
)
SELECT ot.DealerCode,ot.PartCode,
CASE WHEN backorder.totalorderqty > InitialStock THEN 0 ELSE ((InitialStock - backorder.totalorderqty)*(temp.totalorders - rownum + 1)/temp.totalorders)  END 'Stock',
ot.orderqty,
CASE WHEN (InitialStock - backorder.totalorderqty) > temp.totalorderqty THEN InitialStock - backorder.totalorderqty ELSE (CASE WHEN backorder.totalorderqty > InitialStock THEN 0 ELSE InitialStock - backorder.totalorderqty  END) / temp.totalorders END StockAllocated,
ot.ordertype
FROM ordertemp ot
INNER JOIN ordercounttemp temp
ON ot.PartCode = temp.PartCode
AND ot.StockPriority = temp.StockPriority
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.totalorderqty),0) totalorderqty,ISNULL(SUM(B.totalorders),0) totalorders 
from ordercounttemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordercounttemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    AND A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority
GROUP BY A.stockpriority, A.partcode
)backorder
ON backorder.PartCode = temp.PartCode
AND backorder.StockPriority = temp.StockPriority
ORDER BY ot.StockPriority,ot.DealerCode
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change allocate based on a date / time, use change the `ORDER BY`  to `ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.OrderDt`. Check query below.

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
    (DealerCode NVARCHAR(50),
     PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT,
     OrderType NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderDt DATETIME
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( DealerCode,
          PartCode,
          OrderQty,
          OrderType,
          OrderDt)
VALUES  ('D1','A',19,'Urgent','2015-04-15'),
('D2','A',10,'Normal','2015-04-16'),
('D3','A',11,'HotLine','2015-04-17'),
('D1','A',20,'Normal','2015-04-18'),
('D2','A',12,'Normal','2015-04-19'),
('D1','A',40,'Normal','2015-04-20');

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
    (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT)
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',38);

;WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.OrderDt) 'StockPriority',
      sto.stockqty 'InitialStock',ord.OrderDt
from @tblorder ord
left outer join @tblstock sto
on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )

SELECT
    Orders.dealercode,
    Orders.partcode,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
    Orders.orderqty,
    CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
            WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
            ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
    Orders.ordertype,OrderDt
FROM 
    ordertemp Orders
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
    from ordertemp A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
    on A.partcode = B.partcode
    and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
    group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
    ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

Comment: the result from your query is try to make stock zero by allocated qty over than sale order qty. ex. PartCode A (stock=20, order=19, allocated=20). actually the allocated qty must be equal or less than order qty. anyway thanks for your kindly help :)

Comment: Exactly equally is a confusing term. I think best way to handle that is to allocate based in % of stock which can be allocated between orders of same priority. So in our case for part D. Only 50% order qty can be fulfilled. So 50% of each order should be allocated

Comment: to make it easy and not to confusing, first I think no need to allocate by priority (order type). simply let user allocate by order type one by one. that why I asked another question which related to this scenario: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839204/divide-stock-equally-to-sale-order-untill-stock-zero-in-sql-server-2008?lq=1)

Comment: @Sokea - I didn't see any date time colunm `orderty` in the sample data you provided in your order tables? do you have such a column in your actual table?

Comment: yeah it has datetime column in tblOrder, normally user allocated daily (day by day) but FIFO by ordertype and time. the updated logic is be able to allocated qty to all order by allocated qty=1 loop all part till stock=0

Comment: the allocated qty must be allocated to all order, pls. check screenshot excel updated question. :)

Comment: @Sokea - This looks like the third iteration of your question. Constant changes in the question is generally not recommended. If there are additional updates in your question, it might be best to ask another question rather than updating the question again and again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76412/discussion-between-ughai-and-sokea).

Comment: Not been on in a while. For even distribution, another route is a join to a counter where counter < orderqty. You then take exactly the same approach as before, ordered by priority, orderdate etc. Sum up and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - busy day and can't do it at the minute.

Short version - logically your ordering will need to be based on part, priority THEN order amount ascending. You'd need to take account of the running total as you go and the smaller orders might be less than their evenly distributed allocation would be. That would leave you with some odd gaps.

Your "prior" allocation would have to be based on prior "priority" quantities only. You'd then have to calc the distribution within that group.

Lots on the move here atm and waiting for a conference - sorry can't help more atm.

Comment: I have updated my question. if available time, pls. kindly check.. :)