# Divide stock equally to sale order untill stock zero in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a query as below with the result look fine, but one problem is after divided to sale order, if still has stock, it should be divided again to fill-full order qty.

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE
     (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     OrderQty INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblOrder
        ( PartCode,
          OrderQty)
VALUES  ('A',19),
('A',1),
('B',29),
('A',13),
('D',8),
('B',3),
('A',2),
('C',10),
('A',18),
('A',20);

DECLARE @tblStock TABLE
     (PartCode NVARCHAR(50),
     StockQty INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @tblStock
        ( PartCode,
          StockQty)
VALUES  ('A',60),
        ('B',20),
        ('C',10),
        ('D',10)

;WITH ordertemp AS(
SELECT o.PartCode AS partcode,
       COUNT(o.PartCode) AS totalcount,
       SUM(o.OrderQty) AS totalqty,
       MIN(s.StockQty) AS totalstock,
       MIN(s.StockQty)/COUNT(o.PartCode) AS maxallocated
FROM @tblOrder o LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblStock s ON o.PartCode=s.PartCode
GROUP BY o.PartCode)

SELECT o.PartCode,
       ot.totalstock,
       o.OrderQty,
        CASE WHEN o.OrderQty < ot.maxallocated THEN o.OrderQty
            ELSE ot.maxallocated END 'AllocatedQty'
FROM ordertemp ot LEFT OUTER JOIN @tblOrder o ON ot.partcode=o.PartCode
```

the result:

```
PartCode    totalstock  OrderQty    AllocatedQty
A   60  19  10
A   60  1   1
A   60  13  10
A   60  2   2
A   60  18  10
A   60  20  10
B   20  29  10
B   20  3   3
C   10  10  10
D   10  8   8
```

PartCode 'A' has total stock=60, total OrderQty=73 as above query total AllocatedQty=43, thus it has stock available=17 more to divide to sale order. any idea pls. thanks :)

Comment: you have another question to divide stock equally based on priority [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838020/sql-server-2008-allocated-stock-to-qty-of-sale-order-equally-based-on-order-typ). please wait for it to be answered. don't ask repeated questions. if you want to change/enhance the question, edit the question with new updates.

Comment: @ughai thanks for your comment, I just minimize my question to easy to understand.